# The cluster-name certificate expired 42 days ago. Unable to rotate certificate of AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have been using Azure Kubernetes for years and this is the first time I am encountering the situation like this. Can't use my Kubernetes cluster in Azure AKS! Diagnostics tells me cluster certificate expired 42 days ago.

I followed the [documentation to rotate the certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/certificate-rotation) but it does not work and I can't see any logs in Azure activity or audit logs. As you know, AKS is a managed service and you don't have remote access to the server. Any idea how to recover from this certificate expiration issue without having to recreate the AKS cluster from scratch?

This is a platform deficiency, customer should be able to recover following the documentation from the provider but the instructions does not work! I logged an [issue with Microsoft](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/71587) but I hope someone at stackoverflow may have a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was silly thing that was causing azure cli command not to execute when running inside PowerShell ISE! I ran the same command from Azure Cloud Shell and it worked. I was able to rotate the certificate.

When you run in PowerShell it does not prompt y/n and command hangs there! You get to see the prompt when you run in azure cloud shell (Are you sure you want to perform this operation?). Don't know why documentation does not make note of it!

That was it. My AKS cluster back in business.

[image]

Comment: Death to powershell! :)